# ERROR: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hello here is the error that I am currently getting.

```
> [2020-12-02 18:49:37,772] ERROR in app: Exception on /new-mealplan
> [POST] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 2447, in wsgi_app
>     response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
>     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py",
> line 165, in wrapped_function
>     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))   File
> "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1821, in handle_user_exception
>     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise
>     raise value   File "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
>     rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1936, in dispatch_request
>     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)   File "C:\Users\ryand\Desktop\mealplansfree\main-api\api.py", line 125, in
> create_mealplan
>     recipe_id_to_output = str(current_recipe['id'])   File "c:\users\ryand\.virtualenvs\main-api-ucgvpon1\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py",
> line 3208, in __getitem__
>     return list(self[item : item + 1])[0] TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
> 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2020 18:49:37] "POST /new-mealplan HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

With my code I have added str() around current)recipe['id] because after looking around I read that could fix the issue. It did not.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/new-mealplan', methods=['POST'])
def create_mealplan():

    data = request.get_json()
    recipes = data['mealplan_recipes']

    recipe_ids = []

    for recipe in recipes:
        current_recipe = Recipes.query.filter(func.lower(Recipes.recipe_name) == func.lower(recipe))
        if current_recipe:
            recipe_id_to_output = str(current_recipe['id']) # THIS IS THE LINE THE ERROR IS POINTS TOO
            recipe_ids.append(recipe_id_to_output)
    
    return jsonify({ 'Mealplan' : recipe_ids })
```

All I am trying to do is use the recipe names which I submit with a POST request and then take each one I submit and append the recipe ID of the recipe to the recipe_ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite the opposite, you should have added `int(...)` around it.

It tries to add `1` to `item` and it really can't be string then.

Edit: it wasn't this, but instead incorrect usage of the library. Forgot `.first()` after query to actually retrieve the result.

Comment: Ive just tried that but it did not work. Same error. Here is that line: recipe_id_to_output = int(current_recipe['id'])

Comment: Oh, okay. That was a wild guess and potential easy fix, but if that's ruled out then the problem is that `'id'` is a string. You might be using the library wrong. You might have meant `current_recipe.id`.

Comment: That gives me  `recipe_id_to_output = int(current_recipe.id)
AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'id'` So I would think that the original would work.

Comment: I just read the docs and example usages and you need `.first()` after `.filter(...)` to actually get the results.

Comment: Feel free to get a feel of the usage from here: `https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html` - just looking through provided code helped me identify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

how about this: `recipe_id_to_output = "{}".format(current_recipe['id'])`